# How to save the UIImage after multi point cropping the image?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to multi point crop on the image(See the image). Its working fine. My problem is after crop the image the how to I save `UIImage`. I am using the `CAShapeLayer` for crop image. Below code using for multi point crop.

```
- (void)multiPointCrop:(CGPoint)cropPoint
{
    UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [aPath moveToPoint:cropPoint];

    for (NSString *pointString in self.touchPoints) { 
        if ([self.touchPoints indexOfObject:pointString] != 0)
            [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointFromString(pointString)];
    }
    [aPath addLineToPoint:cropPoint];
    [aPath closePath];

    [self setClippingPath:aPath andView:self];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)setClippingPath:(UIBezierPath *)clippingPath andView:(UIView *)view;
{
    if (![[view layer] mask])
        [[view layer] setMask:[CAShapeLayer layer]];

    [(CAShapeLayer*) [[view layer] mask] setPath:[clippingPath CGPath]];
}
```

How to I save `UIImage` from the `CAShapeLayer`? If this is the correct way for multi cropping or any other easy way to achieve this. Please give your ideas, suggestions, source code, etc. Anything always welcome.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rendering layer into a context and creating an image from that context.

```
CALayer *layer = view.layer;
CGSize s = layer.frame.size;
// create context
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, s.width, s.height,
                                             8, (s.width * 4),
                                             colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

// flip Y
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, s.height);    
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

// render layer
[layer renderInContext:context];

CGImageRef imgRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
// here is your image
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef];  

// release owned memory
CGImageRelease(imgRef);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);
```

Comment: Did u succeeded saving the masked image? Plz I need help for the same, tell me if u are done with this.