# How to save cropped image with UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, crop, uibezierpath, clip

I have an app that show an image and the user can "cut" some part of the image.

My problem is that I can´t save the part cutted.

References:

[How to save the UIImage after multi point cropping the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063441/how-to-save-the-uiimage-after-multi-point-cropping-the-image)

This is the method to crop the image:

```
    - (void) setClippingPath:(UIBezierPath *)clippingPath imagen:(UIImageView *)imagenView;
{
    if (![[imagenView layer] mask])
        [[imagenView layer] setMask:[CAShapeLayer layer]];


    [(CAShapeLayer*) [[imagenView layer] mask] setPath:[clippingPath CGPath]];
}
```

Can I save the new image?

Thanks

Comment: How about just generating image from your image view?

Comment: Can you explain how to do it? Please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the comment:

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromView:(UIView *)view {
    CALayer *layer = view.layer;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([layer frame].size);
    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return outputImage;
}
```