# Capture an animating CAShapeLayer in self.view programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, cabasicanimation, cashapelayer

hope you will be good.

I have an circle in my view. I have applied animation on it. So that It animates in anticlockwise direction. Now When I capture the View image using below lines

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

it shows the original layer not the animated part, in simple words that it don't capture the animation.

I got some more words to describe my problem that I have half circle remaining (after animation) , after capturing the image it will be complete circle not the half.

I think I am not much clear but I tried my best to be. If you have any more question regarding my issue please ask me.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13064442/1106035

Comment: I think I am doing something like that. Rendering my layer that contains my View in the Graphics Context. But I am not getting the half circle... I am getting the full circle every time when ever I capture the Self.View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a lot over internet about for 2 hours and at last I found the solution for my problem. Explaining the scenario again. I had a circle that was animating anticlockwise, on push button, I had to take the image of the screen, The problem that occurred was when I push the button it shows the full Circle, (but in actual It should show the half or the remaining part of the circle).

So I found a very simple solution, just replace these lines

```
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

with these

```
CGImageRef screen = UIGetScreenImage();
UIImage *shareImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screen];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: Here is the tutorial for [UIGetScreenImage()](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/screen-capture-using-uigetscreenimage.html)